# Removing whitespaces in text file

Tags: java, file, removing-whitespace

I had to write a simple code that counts words in a text file. Then someone told me, that it's incomplete because when, for example, there will be 2 or more whitespaces in a row, function will count them as a words and result will be incorrect. So i tried to fix it by making a list and removing all " " elements there, but it doesn't seem to work. May you suggest what can be done?

Here's the code as it is now:

```
    int count = 0;
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Test.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fis.read(bytesArray);
    String s = new String(bytesArray);
    String[] data = s.split(" ");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data));
    list.remove(" ");
    data = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of words in the file are " + count);
```

Comment: One extra thing I'd like to bring to your attention. Once you split your text into a list, you do not need to use the `for loop` to count. You can just use `count = data.length`. Using a loop here is a really bad programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be a nerd. You can do it in just one line, using classes in `java.nio.file` package :)

```
int count = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/test.txt")), "UTF-8")
           .trim().split("\\s+").length;
```

to count how many words are in the file. Or

```
String result = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/test.txt")), "UTF-8")
           .trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

to have a single string with content correctly replaced.

Answer (score 3):

You Can achieve this by regex

### String[] data = s.split("\s+");

```
        int count = 0;
        File file = new File("/home/vahid/Documents/test.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        fis.read(bytesArray);
        String s = new String(bytesArray);
        String[] data = s.split("\\s+");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data));
        list.remove(" ");
        data = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of words in the file are " + count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this line of code:

```
String data1 = s.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

before the line:

```
String[] data = data1.split(" ");
```

This should remove any occurrence of 2 or more consecutive spaces in the String s. No need to use `list.remove(" ")`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't remove the line, but just added it above and renamed "data" in your line and "s" in my line with a same name

Comment: @LionKing (Please check my answer again. I corrected a mistake) Did you test the solution ? did it solve your issue ? if yes please remember to mark as answer to help others facing a similar problem.

Comment: yes, it works now, thank you. I didn't mark an answer because 3 minutes did not pass)

Comment: why not do it with the `split`, that is, instead of splitting at every empty space, split at every sequence of spaces (one or more spaces)? no need for two statements

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger That should work too, but the question itself was about removing white space

Comment: seems like removing white space is the "Y" of an "XY" problem - the question is about counting words (between one or more spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle this kind of requirement:
first we should know the character encoding that has been used in the text file.
based on that we should try to read the file byte by byte and at the same time do the processing
Ex: if the file is utf-8 when you read the first byte , we can identify how many more bytes should be read to get the first character.like that , when we found a "." or " " or line break , then we can identify it as a word separator.

This way is efficient (specially for large files) and always file encoding matters.

if we call the String constructor with the byte[] , it always use the default encoding and it also iterate the array byte by byte.